How to synthesize the "du" of "duck"?
I'm experimenting with amazon Polly I see lost of weird issues.
For example, its speaks: /dʌk/ correctly as "duck" but /dʌ/ is synthesized as "do".
I see the same with: http://ipa-reader.xyz/?text=%C3%A6d%20%CB%88h%C9%92k (which I'm told uses polly).
Am I using polly correctly?
Is there a more reliable speech synthethizer?

I wonder if it has been updated, that now /dʌ/ doesn't sound like "do"

/dʌʔ/ seems to work. You could also approximate it with /də/ (at least for some accents).

i’m afraid this is impossible. the vowel /ʌ/ in english is checked, which means this vowel needs a consonant appearing directly after it. i suppose you can try replacing it with a schwa, however in many english dialects it’s a different sound.

How about "duh" ?

@qrsngky that would in fact generate a schwa.

@qrsngky  "duh" comes out as "dew" in Polly

@user48956 very interesting
